# Changing share and security permissions with using batch file

Tags: permissions, batch, batch-file

I want to change folder's share status and security permissions by using batch file.

I tried code below but not worked.

```
net share sharename="C:\" /UNLIMITED
icacls "C:\" /grant Everyone:M
```

Net share for changing share status and icacls for add Everyone permissions.

Even I generate test folder at C drive and tried with C:\test\ but also same. It didn't worked.

Can you guys help me to do this? Thanks!